# Storyboard Locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Hello and thank you for the help :)

I was working on xcode and everything was working fine.
I dont know what i did but suddenly the storyboard stopped working normaly.

What happens is every time i add a new ViewController or any item to the storyboard it freezes in the position where it was dropped i can add buttons and move the buttons in the view.. but i cant move the view itself on the storyboard.

The curious part is that now every project that i have even the new ones.. the same happens.. i dont know what i did and i tried eveyrthing i found on google to fix it.. but nothing worked. anyone has any idea of what it can be?

thank you very much,
Sérgio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some corrupted file in Xcode. Have you tried to delete and reinstall Xcode? Sometimes, that is a solution.

Good luck!

Comment: i did that just now and the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ajpallares answer, did you also clean the cache?

Comment: Maybe installing a different (newer) version?